# Issue about what slider is

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel

I've been searching for nice sliders out in the internet, then I found this site: http://magnumphotos.com/

Does anybody knows which slider they use in it, please??

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to know by "slider"? Is it the image on the top of the page, or what is it? Because I don't see any sliders on that page. [This is a slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/).

Comment: Sorry, I mean carousel.
I got slider on my mind but was trying to say carousel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to see exactly which carousel plugin they use, but a simple google search might suffice with giving you some results.

Personally, I have used [BXSlider](http://bxslider.com/) and [SlidesJS](http://slidesjs.com/), and have been very satisfied with the way they both work.

Comment: I understand your point and i've used another ones too, but the guys asked me one similar to this one, that's why I'm after this plugin.
But thanks anyway!